# iOS, Accessibility - accessibilityElementsHidden = NO; does not take immediate effect

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, accessibility

Setting `self.listViewController.view.accessibilityElementsHidden = NO;` does not take immediate effect.

There is a fraction of a second when you can still swipe right with accessibility, accessibility focus jump to that **listViewController** and remains there, blocked from the main view that covers **listViewController**

`self.listViewController.view.accessibilityElementsHidden = NO;` is the first thing that I do in a method that is passed to `button.addtarget` and its still too slow to disable selected subviews.

What could be the reason for that?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your code `listViewController` initiation?  And eventually adding it to view hierarchy? Maybe you're using `UINavigationController` or modal presents? The getter `.view` may be initializing the VC view depending when it's called. That's likely the place that's causing delay in handling. A route I would explore is to remove the view from its superview. Prep the accessibility and only then re-add it as a subview. A view outside of view hierarchy cannot receive user input.

Comment: Sadly I cannot share more code, but we find the solution through UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, nil);, that I just posted. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me with the solution.

We used..

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, nil);
```

..to update the new screen, right after the sender triggered the layout changes, and right after hiding `self.listViewController.view.accessibilityElementsHidden = NO;`

We set the second parameter to nil, as it takes some fraction of time for the notification to refocus.